# MVC4 View not passing correct modal values

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, modal-dialog

I've been trying to update a flag (Active) in my database. To Do this i have a view that looks the following.
In the view i have records in the databasee i am passing BillPayID in each row in the table in the view. WHat i want to is when a user presses the START or STOP Button the active flag is set to 0 or 1.

THE PROBLEM is, my view is ALWAYS sending the first BillPayID, even if a button on  a different row is clicked.

Can some one please help?

```
@if (Model !=null)
        {
            using (Html.BeginForm("StopScheduled", "Admin", FormMethod.Post, new { }))
            { 
               <table>
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        Account Number 
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Payee ID
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Amount
                    </th>                 
                    <th>
                        Scheduled Date
                    </th>
                     <th>
                        Period
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Active
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Stop/Start Payment
                    </th>           

                </tr>

                @foreach(var item in Model)
                {

                    @Html.HiddenFor(model => item.BillPayID)

                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.AccountNumber)
                            @Html.HiddenFor(model => item.AccountNumber)
                        </td>

                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.PayeeID)
                            @Html.HiddenFor(model => item.PayeeID)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                           $ @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.Amount)
                            @Html.HiddenFor(model => item.Amount)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.ScheduleDate)
                            @Html.HiddenFor(model => item.ScheduleDate)
                        </td>
                         <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.Period)
                             @Html.HiddenFor(model => item.Period)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.Active)
                             @Html.HiddenFor(model => item.Active)
                        </td> 

                        <td>
                            @if (item.Active == 0)
                            {
                                <input type="submit" style="width:100%" value="START" />

                            }
                            else                         
                            {
                                <input type="submit" style="width:100%" value="STOP" />
                            }

                        </td>  

                    </tr>

                }

                </table>
            }

        }
```

this is the controller

```
 [HttpPost]
         public ActionResult StopScheduled([Bind(Prefix = "item")]  BillPayModel model)
         {
             int NewActive = 1;

             if (model.Active == 1)
             {
                 NewActive = 0;
             }

             try
             {
                 if (ModelState.IsValid)
                 {

                     BillPay EditBillPay = db.BillPays.Find(model.BillPayID);
                     EditBillPay.Active = NewActive;
                     EditBillPay.ModifyDate = DateTime.Now;
                     db.Entry(EditBillPay).State = EntityState.Modified;
                     db.SaveChanges();
                     return View(model);
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     ModelState.AddModelError("", "Could not Stop Scheduled Payment");
                 }
             }


             catch (FormatException)
             {
                 ModelState.AddModelError("", "Could not Stop Scheduled Payment");
             }


             return View(model);
         }
```

Answer (score 0):

Hidden fields still have a name and id in html, so in your case your putting x number of hidden fields for BillPayID that will all be named item.BillPayID.

Change the foreach loop to a for loop like so:

```
@for (int i =0; i < Model.Count(); i++)
{
  @Html.HiddenFor(model => Model[i].BillPayID)

  .... rest of your code
}
```

Your view code will send the entire model (IEnumerable) to your controller, which will make determining which row was selected a pain as it does not appear your setting any value in your model that tracks the selected item.

I would suggest you move your start/stop process to another view. If you click on an item in your table, it takes you to a second page that asks you to either start or stop. You can also use a javascript function to send the selected values to your controller.